# Nesting quotations in JavaScript & HTML

Tags: javascript, html

The project I'm working on uses **double quotes** for strings in HTML and JavaScript by default.
This has been decided and there is nothing I can do about it.
What hasn't been decided however, is how we should deal with nested quotations.

There are three options I can think of:

1. Begin with outermost quote & alternate.

```
element.innerHTML = "<a href='...'></a>";
<button onclick="alert('...')"></button>
```

2. Begin with innermost quote & alternate.

```
element.innerHTML = '<a href="..."></a>';
<button onclick='alert("...")'></button>
```

3. Escape everything.

```
element.innerHTML = "<a href=\"...\"></a>";
<button onclick="alert(&quot;...&quot;)"></button>
```

Which is the best practice in terms of overall convenience, style, safety, maintainability, portability, etc.? And please suggest a better way if there is other than the above.

Comment: It's a bit ridiculous to require double quotes inside string literals.

Comment: None of those are a good idea, because escaping strings in HTML is tedious, and because [inline attribute handlers have terrible scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045). Attach event listeners using Javascript instead

Answer (score 0):

I think the examples you gave are structured a little weird. Regardless, here's another option that I think you'll like better: *template literals*. You use backticks to define them. However, to use it effectively, you'll have to define your function outside of the string you passed into the HTML parameter for `onclick`.

Here's an example:

```
<button onclick="foo()">Click Me!</button>
<script>
  function foo() {
    alert(`"Hello"`);
  }
</script>
```